# width of <h*> element flows 100% always

Tags: html, css

When setting the background color of a `<H1>` tag(or any `<H*>` tag) the element spans the length of the body element of the HTML page.

```
<H1>A</H1>

H1
{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

The following image shows the problem and ideal result

[image]

I can get the desired effect by statically setting the width of the `<H1>` tag in the css like

```
H1
{
    background: #ddd;
    width: 10px;
}
```

The problem with this is that if I have text inside the `<H1>` tag that is bigger than 10px it will overflow the background.

Answer (score 6):

`h1` elements use `display: block`, which is the correct default behavior. It prevents subsequent content from appearing on the same line, and allows borders and backgrounds to be the (appropriate) full width of the content region.

If you need the element to only take the width of the text, use one of the following methods:

1. an inner element such as `<h1><span>h1</span></h1>` so that you can select the inner element to provide the background.

   ```css
   span {
     background-color: #CCC;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1><span>h1</span></h1>
   ```
2. `display: inline` if you want the heading to be treated as inline text and flow appropriately.

   ```css
   h1 {
     background-color: #CCC;
     display: inline;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>h1</h1>

   <!-- here's where this fails -->

   <h1>h1 again</h1>
   ```
3. `display: inline-block` if you want the heading to have the features of a block element (such as being able to set padding, height, and width)

   ```css
   h1 {
     background-color: #CCC;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 2px 3px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>h1</h1>

   <!-- here's where this fails -->

   <h1>h1 again</h1>
   ```
4. `float: left; clear: both;` if you want the heading to align to the left, but ignore other floated elements. The issue with this one is that it will no longer collapse margins.

   ```css
   h1 {
     background-color: #CCC;
     clear: both;
     float: left;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <h1>h1</h1>

   <h1>h1 again</h1>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

No need to set the width. Just update the display type from `block` to `inline` or `inline-block`, if needed.

Something like this:

```
h1.ib {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3f2obr1/

Answer (score 2):

You can control the layout mode of the elements with the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property.

However, there is a problem: most values that make the box shrink to its content instead of growing to cover the container block are inline-level, e.g. `inline-block`, `inline-table`, `inline-flex`. That means that, if there is other inline content around your headers, they will be displayed in the same line (if they fit).

Probably, you don't want that. Then, you can use `display: table`:

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
Before
<h1>h1</h1>
Middle
<h1>h1 again</h1>
After
```

The `table` display is block-level, so the header will be in a different line than surrounding inline content. But unlike `block`, the contents are layed out using the table layout, so the header will shrink to its content.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Jack Pattishall and zzzzBov beat me to it.

You don't actually have to set the width. There's a CSS property available for solving your problem. `display:inline`

An inline element only takes up as much width as necessary.

Just set your heading to this.

```
h1 {
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a byte-saving way to do it:

```
H1 {
display: inline;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

<h1>Your Text Here</h1><br>
```